# Changing position of editor in Bibtex style file

Tags: bibtex

I am referring to an author appearing in a collection. This is what my bibtex entry looks like:

```
@InCollection{goguel78,
author = {Goguel, J.},
title = {Scale-dependent rockslide mechanisms, with emphasis
on the role of pore fluid vaporization},
booktitle = {Rockslides and Avalanches: Natural Phenomena},
pages = {693--705},
year = {1978},
editor = {Barry Voight},
volume = {1},
publisher = {Elsevier Science Ltd},
address = {New York},
}
```

Unfortunately my .bst style file seems to be screwed up, as the the editor part (Voight, B. (editor)) appears inbetween "In" and the book's title:

[image]

I'd rather have it at after the title. What changes do I have to make to my style file in order to achieve this? As far I understood the code I have to do something to  the `format.in.ed.booktitle` function:

```
FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.sentence
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check  % scroll down for function
      format.publisher.address output
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.chapter.pages output
      format.edition output
      format.isbn output
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  format.doi output
  format.url output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

%%% to be edited
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ format.booktitle duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      editor "editor" format.names.ed duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        {
          " " *
          get.bbl.editor
          "(" swap$ * "), " *
          * swap$
          * }
      if$
      word.in swap$ *
    }
  if$
}
```

Thanks in advance for any helpful hint.

Comment: Having the editor mentioned before the book title is fairly common practice, actually. Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: Is it? I didn't know that, it just seemed somewhat confusing to me to have the editor mentioned after the word "In"... I built my own style file on the basis of apalike.sty

Comment: I think you have two main options; (i) find an existing bibliography style that handlies the formatting of the `editor` field to your liking and copy that file's code into your bst file; or (ii) run the `makebst` utility to create a bespoke bibliography style.